# Selected selector in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, selector

How can I transform the following jQuery code to working JavaScript code?

**jQuery**

```
$('select :visible:selected').each(function(i) {
  // instructions
}
```

The visible selector I've already implemented with JS. Or is there a better solution?

**JavaScript**

```
for (var i=0;i<$('select').length;i++) {
  if ($('select')[i].style.visibility == "visible") {
    // instructions
  }    
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: And you are still using jQuery in the "javascript" part

Comment: Ok but I need this like the second code I posted. The first one doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selected takes selected OPTION from SELECT list. So to get all selected options from all visible SELECTs from the page with pure JavaScript

```
var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
for(var i=0; i<selects.length; i++) {
   var select = selects[i];

   if(select.style.visibility == 'visible'){
     for(var j=0; j<select.options.length; j++) {
       if(select.options[j].selected){
          // ... your code goes here ..
       }
     }
   }
}
```

**UPDATE** So if I undestand you corectly you need all [selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) OPTIONS from ALL [visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) SELECTs and you CAN use jQuery

```
$('select:visible option:selected').each(function(i,elm) {
  // instructions
  alert(elm.value);
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

iQuery *is* javascript, so the "jQuery code" *is* working JavaScript code.

additionally, the fact that you're using in your second example, too (`$('select')`) makes me wonder why you don't just simply use your first one.

if you don't want to use jQuery and stick to "plain" javascript instead, it should look like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
for (var i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
  var element = elements[i];

  // use:
  element.style.visibility // to check for visibility
  element.selectedIndex // to check if/what option is selected (-1 = no selection)
  // a 'select' doesn't have a 'selected' property
  // because it's the <option> that gets selected

  // so we end up:
  if (element.style.visibility == "visible" && element.selectedIndex >= 0) {
    // instructions
  } 
}
```

more information about [selectedindex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [selected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534623%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: on `<select multiple>` selectedIndex returns the id of the first selected option - for this solution thats enough because we only want to check if *any* option is selected and don't need to know wich one. i don't see the problem

Comment: The OP didn't ask how to find the first selected or if one of many was selected. He loops over them all, ergo is he looking for all of them, ergo will your solution not work for him.

Comment: my code also doesn't find "only the first selected". it does exactly what the jquery-example dioes: find all `select`-elements that have a selection (regardless of wether it's a multiple select with one or more selected options or a single-select with a selection). none of the codes (not mine and not the jquery example) search for options, it's just about the `select`s and if they have a selection or not.